# Ncurses box() function only works with a getch() before it

Tags: c++, user-interface, ncurses

I am getting a very strange "bug" I guess you could call it. I am using Xcode to develop a simple game and wanted to add some simple graphics.

To do this I decided to use the `ncurses` library.

In learning how to use `ncurses`, I began mucking around creating windows, one of the functions I will definitely be using later (possibly for health bars or something) is the `box()` function that surrounds a window in a `box()`. The simple test I did was to create a new window in the centre of the `strscr` window and then call `box()` on it. The code for this is below:

```
WINDOW *AboutWindow;
int width=60,height=12;
int OffsetX=0,OffsetY=0;
OffsetX = (getmaxx(stdscr) - width) / 2;
OffsetY = ((getmaxy(stdscr) - height) / 2);
AboutWindow = newwin(height, width, OffsetY, OffsetX);
getch();
box(AboutWindow, 0, 0);
//getch();
wrefresh(AboutWindow);
```

The odd "bug" is that the box will only get drawn if `getch()` is called before I call the `box()` function. If I comment out the `getch()` the box, does not get drawn.

I am completely flunked as to why this is happening.

Comment: Does replacing the last getch() with std::cout << std::flush have the same effect?

Comment: no that didnt work im afraid. still puts the window there and flickers with the outline of the box for a brief millisecond then dissapears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know the question is old, but for the future reference:
There is a way to get it to work.

After reading a tutorial about ncurses here http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO I was wondering how is it that if you `printw()` and then `getch()` you don't have to run `refresh()`. I figured that it is invoked in `getch()` and it refreshes `stdscr` which overrides output from any other windows.

So in order to keep the window on screen and get keyboard input you have to use `wgetch(WINDOW*)`.

Your code would look like that:

```
WINDOW *AboutWindow;
int width=60,height=12;
int OffsetX=0,OffsetY=0;
OffsetX = (getmaxx(stdscr) - width) / 2;
OffsetY = ((getmaxy(stdscr) - height) / 2);
AboutWindow = newwin(height, width, OffsetY, OffsetX);
box(AboutWindow, 0, 0);
wgetch(AboutWindow); //also invokes wrefresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

call `refresh()` before any windows related functions.

I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, after an hour of fiddling I've found that there isn't a lot you can do to get rid of the `getch()`, to my knowledge(which is not very extensive by any means!), however to get it so that you don't have to press a button every time to get past that line of code, you put a `halfdelay()` time on it, the following code works perfectly.

```
WINDOW *AboutWindow;
int width=60,height=12;
int OffsetX=0,OffsetY=0;
OffsetX = (getmaxx(stdscr) - width) / 2;
OffsetY = ((getmaxy(stdscr) - height) / 2);
AboutWindow = newwin(height, width, OffsetY, OffsetX);
halfdelay(1);
getch();
box(AboutWindow, 0, 0);
wrefresh(AboutWindow);
```

- please note that to exit `halfdelay` mode call the `cbreak()` function.